# How to remove sitemap link in the footer? - Magento2

Tags: magento2, magento2.4, footer, sitemaps

To remove sitemap link in the footer, I tried to add this on

Magento_Theme/layout/default.xml

```
<referenceBlock name="sitemap-link" remove="true"/>
```

or

```
<referenceBlock name="sitemap-link-footer" remove="true"/>
```

but still sitemap link is showing on footer

Comment: Default Magento luma theme do not have sitemap link in footer. It is added externally. Just search name in layout for link and remove it

Comment: @Pawan You're right. Thanks to your hint, I could find this is related with one of external module and remove the 'Sitemap' link in the footer. Thanks! 

Comment: welcome :) glad to know you found solution with the help of my comment!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the magento2 default theme there is no sitemap link in the footer, so check in your custom theme, In general, most of the theme provides the footer links from the cms blocks, so read the theme documentation that will help.